# How to add data attribute in Rails bootstrap form select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-select

I found this Bootstrap Select project and its gem for Rails. I want to implement search in the select tag.

I do inspect element and here is the HTML source:

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
  <option>Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>
  <option>Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>
  <option>Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>
</select>
```

How do I add data-live-search="true" inside my form select tag?

My form select

```
  <%= f.select :status_cont, [["Activo", "Activo"], ["Inactivo", "Inactivo"]], {:prompt => "Elegir"}, { class: "form-control", 'live-search' => 'true' } %>
```

buts its not work
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4Ul0.png)

Comment: Did you try `:"data-live-search" => "true`?

Comment: yes i do, data-live-search but is not working

Comment: Well if it did show, then there's probably something wrong with the JavaScript instead. My guess is Turbolinks. Try changing the body tag to this: `<body data-no-turbolink>` and hit refresh.

Comment: hi, where i can changing???? thanks

Comment: application.html.erb add `data-no-turbolink` to the body tag. ex: `<body data-no-turbolink>`

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
<%= f.select :status_cont, [["Activo", "Activo"], ["Inactivo", "Inactivo"]], {:prompt => "Elegir"}, { class: "form-control", data: { live_search: 'true' } } %>
```